# Unexpected behavior in PHP - Same code gives correct results in C# and Python

Tags: c#, php, python, math

Why does PHP return INF (infinity) for the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$n = 1234;
$m = 0;

while ($n > 0)
{
    $m = ($m * 10) + ($n % 10);
    $n = $n / 10;
}

var_dump($m);
?>
```

The expected result was **4321**, but PHP returned **INF**, float type:

```
float INF
```

I wrote the same code in Python and C# and got the expected output - **4321**

*Python*

```
n = 1234
m = 0

while (n > 0):
    m = (m * 10) + (n % 10)
    n = n / 10

print m
```

*C#*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 1234;
    int m = 0;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        m = (m * 10) + (n % 10);
        n = n / 10;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(m);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but it returns `INF` because the number becomes to big. If you alter the test to `$n > 1` it returns the expected result…

Comment: As an aside, Python 3 moved integer division to the // operator and made / into regular floating point division, so Python 3 will return `inf` just like PHP does.

Comment: @Kevin Very interesting, thanks for pointing that out. I was using 2.7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In php `$n / 10` will return a float number, not integer.

So `$n > 0` will always be `true`.

Change `while($n > 0)`

to `while($n > 1)` or `while((int)$n > 0)`, then you will get the right result.

Answer (score 6):

PHP is typeless and converts 'on the fly'.

That means, you $n will never be '0' or lower, because $n will be a 'float', when needed.

Try checking for < 1, and you should be fine.

Just to clarify this, $n will behave like this:

$n = 1234
$n = 123.4
$n = 12.34
$n = 1.234
$n = 0.1234
$n = 0.01234
etc.

Meaning: $n will always approach 0, but never reach it.
That makes $m infinite, since the loop itself is infinite.

Answer (score 5):

What is happening is that:

```
$n = $n / 10;
```

Is performing float division instead of integer division, thus $n never reaches a value of 0, it just approaches a value of 0, i.e. 0.0...1234.

Changing the above code to this:

```
$n = (int)($n / 10);
```

Will fix the problem.

Comment: Casting it to integer gives the following result: int 43210

Comment: That was not what I was expecting, I am afraid I don't quite know why it gives you that at the moment..

Comment: Casting operators have precedence above arithmetic operators, so you're only casting the $n variable, and not the result of the division. [PHP operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @Ivar Bonsaksen Indeed, adding brackets around $n / 10 casts it as expected.

Answer (score 2):

the correct algoritm uses floor()

```
<?php
$n = 1234;
$m = 0;

while ($n > 0)
{
    $m = $m * 10 + ($n % 10);
    $n = floor($n / 10);
}

var_dump($m);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more that likely because of typical floating point arithmetic.

If you use BCMath Arbitrary Precision Mathematics it does not have the same effect.

```
$n = 1234;
$m = 0;

while ($n > 0)
{
    $m = bcmul($m, 10) + bcmod($n, 10);
    $n = bcdiv($n, 10);
}

var_dump($m);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/FYNCyN

See also:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = intval($n / 10);
```

That seems to have solved the problem.